# How to multiprocess pandas dataframe using map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ffmpeg, multiprocessing

So I am able to multiprocess with the map function but when I add another variable it does not work.

```
       name                                    url
0   camera1     http://x.x.x.x:83/mjpg/video.mjpg
1   camera2      http://x.x.x.x:82/mjpg/video.mjpg
2   camera3     http://x.x.x.x:80/mjpg/video.mjpg
3   camera4  http://x.x.x.x:8001/mjpg/video.mjpg
4   camera5   http://x.x.x.x:8001/mjpg/video.mjpg
5   camera6     http://x.x.x.x:81/mjpg/video.mjpg
6   camera7     http://x.x.x.x:80/mjpg/video.mjpg
7   camera8     http://x.x.x.x:88/mjpg/video.mjpg
8   camera9     http://x.x.x.x:84/mjpg/video.mjpg
9  camera10      http://x.x.x.x:80/mjpg/video.mjpg
```

Here is my pandas dataframe. I have actual IPs btw.

The code below works. I have only 1 variable in the subprocess run.  What the code is doing is recording the http urls all at once.

```
camera_df = pd.read_csv('/home/test/streams.csv',low_memory=False)
def ffmpeg_function(*arg):
        subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-t", "10", "-i", *arg, "-f", "null", "/dev/null"], capture_output=True)

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
camera_df['url'] = p.map(ffmpeg_function, camera_df['url'])
```

But when I try to add another variable to name the mp4 file that I am recording it does not work. What I am trying to do is record the http url and name the mp4 file after the name in the column next to it

```
camera_df = pd.read_csv('/home/test/streams.csv',low_memory=False)
def ffmpeg_function(*arg):
        subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-t", "10", "-i", *arg, *arg], capture_output=True)

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
video_file = '/home/test/test.mp4'
camera_df['url'] = p.map(ffmpeg_function, [camera_df['url'], [camera_df['url']])
```

I get the following error below

`TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series`

Comment: I read some where that using pandas was faster

Comment: How would pandas be faster here? Pandas is fast if you want to use the pandas API to do data analysis. Not if you are just going to iterate over it, which is effectively what using `pool.map` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no good reason to involve `pandas` in any of this. Just use:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv

def ffmpeg_function(args):
    result = subprocess.run(["/usr/bin/ffmpeg", "-y", "-t", "10", "-i", *args], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout # not sure what you actually need...

with open('/home/test/streams.csv') as f, mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # skip header in csv
    next(reader)
    result = pool.map(ffmpeg_function, reader)
```

If you insist on using pandas to do this, then just use `itertuples`:

```
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/test/streams.csv')
    df['whatever'] = pool.map(
        ffmpeg_function, 
        df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)
    )
```

There are a lot of different ways you could have done this.

Note, in the `ffmep_function` you have to actually *return something*. Not exactly sure what you want. You may want to use `return result.stdout.decode()` if you want a string instead of `bytes` objects.

Comment: that doesnt work btw

Comment: @D0n what doesn't work, exactly?